# NotApplicable Response is XACML policy

Tags: authorization, xacml, xacml3, abac, wso2-identity-server

Why am i getting NotApplicable response in XACML policy ? Please find my XACML policy, request and response below. In my policy, i have main target element which matches username. I am using wso2is-5.1.0 for my testing.

#### XACML policy

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="TestPolicyWithTarget" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
       <Target>
          <AnyOf>
             <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">abhishek</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                </Match>
             </AllOf>
          </AnyOf>
       </Target>
       <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="TestRule">
          <Target>
             <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                   <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo1</AttributeValue>
                      <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                   </Match>
                </AllOf>
             </AnyOf>
             <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                   <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                      <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                   </Match>
                </AllOf>
             </AnyOf>
          </Target>
          <Condition>
             <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
                   <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"></Function>
                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">abhishek</AttributeValue>
                   <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                </Apply>
             </Apply>
          </Condition>
       </Rule>
    </Policy>
```

#### XACML Request

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo1</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">abhishek</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

#### XACML Response

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <Result>
        <Decision>NotApplicable</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok"/>
        </Status>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your policy in the [Axiomatics Policy Server](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/axiomatics-policy-server.html) and I also get NotApplicable. What effect were you expecting? The policy behaves correctly. The Policy target and the Rule target are both matched.

The condition is also matched but given you use a not() function, it becomes false and therefore the rule does not apply which leads to ***NotApplicable***.

[image: Policy simulation inside the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point]

If you want Deny back, then you need to have a catch all ***Deny*** rule after the ***Permit*** rule.

[image: New policy structure]

And here is the code.

```
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="TestPolicyWithTarget" Version="1.0" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable">
    <xacml3:Description/>
    <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:AnyOf>
            <xacml3:AllOf>
                <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">abhishek</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"  AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                </xacml3:Match>
            </xacml3:AllOf>
        </xacml3:AnyOf>
    </xacml3:Target>
    <xacml3:Rule RuleId="TestRule" Effect="Permit">
        <xacml3:Target>
            <xacml3:AnyOf>
                <xacml3:AllOf>
                    <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo1</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"  AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </xacml3:Match>
                </xacml3:AllOf>
            </xacml3:AnyOf>
            <xacml3:AnyOf>
                <xacml3:AllOf>
                    <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"  AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                    </xacml3:Match>
                </xacml3:AllOf>
            </xacml3:AnyOf>
        </xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:Condition >
            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not">
                <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
                    <xacml3:Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">abhishek</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"  AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                </xacml3:Apply>
            </xacml3:Apply>
        </xacml3:Condition>
    </xacml3:Rule>
    <xacml3:Rule RuleId="0e96abf0-e2f5-495b-8df1-bb3f2987e949" Effect="Deny">
        <xacml3:Description>Catch all</xacml3:Description>
        <xacml3:Target/>
    </xacml3:Rule>
</xacml3:Policy>
```